# JNI return object from c++ to java

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am new to NDK and JNI. I have a struct which contains 2 uint64_t variables, I want to pass these as an jobject to the java class.

Java class

```
public class MyClass {
    private long mVar1;
    private long mVar2;

    public MyClass() {
    }

    public MyClass(final long mVAR1, final long mVar2) {
        this.mVar1 = mVar1;
        this.mVar2 = mVar2;
    }

    public long getVar1() {
        return this.mVar1;
    }


    public long getVar2() {
        return this.mVar2;
    }
}
```

Here is my JNI

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_my_class_getMyClass(JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj) {
    clazz = env->FindClass("my/package/test/MyClass");
    methodID = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>", "(JJ)V");
    return convertMyClass(env, test.getMyClass());
}
```

Here is the convert

```
jobject convertMyClass(JNIEnv * env, MyClass myClass) {

    jobject jmyclass = env->NewObject(clazz, methodID);

        return jmyclass;
    }
```

How can i add arguments to the convertMyClass.

Comment: Here's a code example of calling a class constructor with parameters from JNI:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740139/android-jni-newobject-does-not-save-values-when-passing-it-to-java

Comment: note that Java does not have unsigned types